# account permmison inside action

Tags: cleos, permissions, eosio-cpp, inline-action, constructor

my code is

```
authority auth{.threshold = 1,.keys = {{.key = key,.weight = 1}},
            .accounts = {{.permission = {.actor = get_self(),.permission"eosio.code"_n},.weight = 1}},
            .waits = {}
        };

action(
        permission_level{myAccount, "active"_n},
        "eosio"_n,
        "updateauth"_n,
        std::make_tuple(myAccount, "active"_n, "owner"_n, auth))
        .send();
```

Ok i want to give farmeraccoun permission to execture action in eosio.code on my behalf.
the struct for authority is as follow

```
struct key_weight
{
    eosio::public_key key;
    uint16_t weight;
};

struct permission_level_weight
{
    eosio::permission_level permission;
    uint16_t weight;
};

struct wait_weight
{
    uint32_t wait_sec;
    uint16_t weight;
};

struct authority
{
    uint32_t threshold;
    std::vector<key_weight> keys;
    std::vector<permission_level_weight> accounts;
    std::vector<wait_weight> waits;
};
```

The problem is the struct permission_level_weight has eosio::permission_level permission; which donot contain information about .actor and permission. please any one link the two struct

```
struct perm_level
{
    name actor;
    name permission;
};

struct permission_level_weight
{
    eosio::permission_level permission;
    uint16_t weight;
};
```